# Coinbase - converted BTC to Euros but now Euro amount has changed

Tags: exchanges, coinbase.com, exchange-fees, trade

Recently I converted some of my BTC to Euros on Coinbase. I needed €5000 euros exactly. The fee was €74.50, ok fine. That left me with €4925.50.

I haven't made one transaction since, but logged in now and see that I have only €4248.63 and price is Euro price is €0.86.

I have to say, i'm confused here. Can anyone explain? Thanks.

Comment: 1.5% is quite a large fee for one trade. I'd consider using other platforms to cash out next time. Kraken is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

> Recently I converted some of my BTC to Euros on Coinbase. I needed €5000 euros exactly. The fee was €74.50, ok fine. That left me with €4925.50.

Are you sure the btc2eur conversion was successful?

> I haven't made one transaction since, but logged in now and see that I have only €4248.63 and price is Euro price is €0.86.

This could look like the btc2eur conversion was unsuccessful and so your "account value" has ever since shrunk.

Or could look like the first action was really btc2usd, not btc2eur. This one is somewhat common.

Double check everything and ask their customer support.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indication that while the currency is being displayed as EUR, the underlying currency is a different one. The price fluctuations between the underlying currency and EUR would cause the EUR balance to change. Check your settings and see if you have it set to display all balances in EUR.

If you are sure the balance is definitely in EUR, then it could be that Coinbase has deducted a fee from your account. If you want clarification, it is worth opening a ticket with Coinbase and ask them to look into the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's strange. When I open my assets page, at first it shows the reduced Euro amount at the price at 0.86 EUR. After 20 minutes or so, it shows my expected amount with 1.00 EUR. Maybe a bug? Don't know.